# MVC5 Routing change URL to inclide class name attribute rather than ID and with show action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

My default route config is declared as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If I have a teams controller and I want to show the teams the URL is:

```
http://example.com/Teams/Show/1
```

Without affecting the rest of the routes is there a means of configuring this so it would just show as:

```
http://example.com/Teams/Arizona
```

Comment: I would have the class attribute from the model, is it possible to ammend the URL on document.ready?

Comment: i think this will work in document.ready...window.location.href=url+"#"+class attr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. One way is to use attribute routing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

In your `RouteConfig` or equivalent:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

And in your controller of interest:

```
[Route("Teams/{teamName}")]
public ActionResult ShowTeam(string teamName)
{
     var teamInfoViewModel = Service.GetViewModel(teamName);
     return View(teamInfoViewModel);
}
```

Comment: @Jay Me alegro de poder ayudar a